# multiplying moving rectangles in python (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have two questions:

1. I want to make several rectangles, moving randomly. I am at a point where i
   can do it with one rectangle but i don't get it how to multiply them.
2. I am a beginner so i have copied this example and modified it in my favor but i don't know exactly why i have to write everytime the "self" and the "**init**". It seems to be common to name those parameters in this manner.

I looked both questions up several times but didn't find a satisfying answer.

here the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from random import *

class simulation: 
    def __init__(self, anzahl, master = None):

        self.master = master
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, width= 2736, height= 1824)
        self.rectangle = self.canvas.create_rectangle(500, 380, 515, 395, fill = "black") 
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.movement()

    def movement(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.rectangle, randint(-10,10), randint(-10,10))
        self.canvas.after(100, self.movement)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = Tk()
    master.title("Simulation")
    simulation = simulation(master)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The "init" and "self" keywords are an essential part of how Objects work in Python. I think you should spend some time learning about Objects in Python, as it will make everything clearer for you (since Tkinter is very "Object Oriented").

Comment: ***"make several rectangles"***: You code didn't show this. Read about [tutorial - lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will help you, make an object for each player and the canvas packed ones in order not to hide other players ...

```
from tkinter import *

from random import *

class simulation: 
    def __init__(self, master , canvas , color):
        self.master = master
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.rectangle = canvas.create_rectangle(500, 380, 515, 395, fill=color)


    def movement(self):
        canvas.move(self.rectangle, randint(-10,10), randint(-10,10))
        self.canvas.after(100, self.movement)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(master, width=2736, height=1824)
    canvas.pack()
    master.title("Simulation")
    player1 = simulation(master, canvas,"red")
    player2 = simulation(master,canvas, "black")
    player1.movement()
    player2.movement()


    mainloop()
```